# Search through all git commits with a grep and then format the results

Tags: git, git-log

How do I search through all git commits with a grep and then format the results with just the commit hash and the commit notes.

I have tried something like this.

```
git log --pretty=format:%H %N --grep=mysearchtext
```

Not sure if I am missing some command pipes somewhere.

Comment: By "commit notes", do you mean the commit message? Or the notes of the commit (see [git-notes(1](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html)))?

Comment: I meant the commit message. Sorry. Wasn't sure about the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the commit message and not the [notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html), you don't want to use `%N`. Perhaps `%s` would be better, or `%s %b`. That's up to you. Also, make sure you single or double quote the `--pretty` flag so it's not split into two arguments

```
git log "--pretty=format:%H %s" --grep=mysearchtext
```

Comment: YEAH!! Works like a charm! Thanks. Is it the norm to have the format before the filter?

Comment: There's no norm about the ordering of the options.

Comment: ok that's good to hear. Also why was your entire pretty format option part of a whole string?

Comment: You mean why `"--pretty=format:%H %s"` instead of `--pretty=format:%H %s`? Because otherwise `%s` won't be part of the `--pretty` option and Git will barf over the standalone and nonsensical `%s`.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Shouldn't it be `--pretty="%H %s"`?

Comment: @HaralanDobrev: Doesn't matter. They're both okay.

Comment: When you guys use git. Do you normally use git bash? Or do you guys prefer going the GUI way?

Comment: If I need to visualize non-trivial branch relationships I use gitk, and for non-trivial diffs I use meld or kdiff3. Apart from that I work exclusively in the shell (which in my case is zsh and not bash).

Comment: @Methedex As you're using "git bash" I assume you work with Windows. Perhaps you are not used to working on the command line, but this is because Windows Command Prompt is a terrible experience. You could try Cygwin (or similar emualtor) or switching to *nix?

Comment: Yup. Working on windows. And yes the CMD is horrible. I tend to use power-shell more as it is way more powerful. Have to stay on windows though, because of C#.